# Python 3 Tkinter - NameError: name 'price_overall_release' is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The aim of this code is to make the button create a label, where it would add or subtract the number provided and display it depending on whether the first attribute for "release_button()" is "add" or "sub".

So as an example to explain it better: 
(lets say "price_release(game_id)" = 19.99)

```
price_overall_release = price_overall_release + price_releases[game_id]
```

"price_overall_release" is equal to 0 at the start. When the button is pressed, it will add "price_release(game_id)" to the 0 and then replace "price_overall_release" with itself. (press once: 0 = 0 + 19.99, press twice: 19.99 = 19.99 + 19.99)

For some reason though, it doesn't like that, and it will spit out this error instead:

```
price_overall_release = price_overall_release + price_releases[game_id]
NameError: name 'price_overall_release' is not defined
```

I am not sure what the problem is. It doesn't make much sense to me since from what I can tell, it HAS been defined.

```
price_overall_release = 0
# A definition for adding and subtracting to the price at the bottom.
def release_button(add_or_sub, game_id):
    global price_overall_release
    if add_or_sub == "add":
        price_releases[game_id] = float(price_releases[game_id])
        price_overall_release = price_overall_release + price_releases[game_id]
        price_releases[game_id] = str(price_releases[game_id])

        # Declare and show.
        price_overall_release = str(price_overall_release)
        label_overallprice_releases = Label(new_release_window, text="$"+price_overall_release,
                            bg = releases_price_colour, fg = "black", relief = "sunken", borderwidth = 1, font = gui_font_10)
        amount_ordered_release = Label(new_release_window, text = amount_release,
                            bg = releases_price_colour, fg = "black", borderwidth = 1, font = gui_font_10)

        label_overallprice_releases.grid(row = 12, column = 3, padx = 7.5, pady = space_between) # +
        price_overall_release = float(price_overall_release)

        return price_overall_release
    else:
        price_releases[game_id] = float(price_releases[game_id])
        price_overall_release = price_overall_release - price_releases[game_id]
        price_releases[game_id] = str(price_releases[game_id])

        # Declare and show.
        price_overall_release = str(price_overall_release)
        label_overallprice_releases = Label(new_release_window, text="$"+price_overall_release,
                            bg = releases_price_colour, fg = "black", relief = "sunken", borderwidth = 1, font = gui_font_10)

        label_overallprice_releases.grid(row = 12, column = 3, padx = 7.5, pady = space_between) # +
        price_overall_release = float(price_overall_release)

        return price_overall_release

# Buttons.
releases_button_colour_add = ("forestgreen")
releases_button_colour_sub = ("firebrick")
#   1._________ 
button_game1_add = Button(new_release_window, text = "+", bg = releases_button_colour_add, font = "Helvetica 10", fg = "white",
                      width = 2, command = lambda: release_button("add", 3))
button_game1_sub = Button(new_release_window, text = "-", bg = releases_button_colour_sub, font = "Helvetica 10", fg = "white",
                      width = 2, command = lambda: release_button("sub", 3))
#   2._________
button_game2_add = Button(new_release_window, text = "+", bg = releases_button_colour_add, font = "Helvetica 10", fg = "white",
                      width = 2, command = lambda: release_button("add", 4))
button_game2_sub = Button(new_release_window, text = "-", bg = releases_button_colour_sub, font = "Helvetica 10", fg = "white",
                      width = 2, command = lambda: release_button("sub", 4))
```

Note: This code is inside another definition. The other definition is basically just a definition to hold all of the buttons, labels and images for a Toplevel() window.

Comment: Please explain "all of this code is inside another definition".  In that case the global named `price_overall_release` might not be initialized. If the first line that you listed here is inside a function definition, it did not create a global.

Comment: The definition is inside another definition. The definition that it is inside of it is basically just a definition to hold all of the buttons, labels and images for a Toplevel() window.

Comment: Your code, as you presented it, does define `price_overall_release.`  But I know from long experience that Python doesn't make a mistake about what variables are defined.  So I conclude that the actual program, which you didn't present, has some sort of problem.  Most likely it's related to Python's scoping rules.  If you want some help with this you must present more of your actual code, or, preferably, reduce your code to the shortest possible example of the failure.